# Android : Compress images issue

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to compress images before uploading them to the server, without losing quality.

my principle is to scale the image to a height and width that does not exceed 4000 pixels. for example, if the height is 5000 pixels, then I change it to 4000, and I change the width also in proportion to the height. otherwise I keep the current dimensions if they do not exceed 4000.

then I compress the bitmap to a preset quality of 80%.

it works fine in most smartphones, and I got good quality with a very small image size (1MB around).

the problem here is that it doesn't work in a very limited number of smartphones. I find that the size of the image is not changed (6-5MB), and in the exif data the height and the width are -1

this is my compression algorithm

```
private fun compressImage(
    source : Uri,
    maxSize : Int,
    quality : Int,
    fileNameSuffix : String
) : File?
{
    // Create bitmap from uri.
    val sourceAsBitmap : Bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(source) ?: return null
    
    // The width and height of the original image.
    val sourceWidth : Float = sourceAsBitmap.width.toFloat()
    val sourceHeight : Float = sourceAsBitmap.height.toFloat()
    
    // #######################################################################################
    
    // The height and width of the image after scale must not exceed 4000 pixels.
    // So here, we determine if the current height and width exceed 4000, we choose the 4000,
    // otherwise, we keep the current dimensions.
    // After determining the max between the height and width, we calculate their proportion 
    // to correctly scale the image
    
    val minWidth : Float = min(sourceWidth, maxSize.toFloat()) / sourceWidth
    val minHeight : Float = min(sourceHeight, maxSize.toFloat()) / sourceHeight
    
    val percentage : Float = min(minWidth, minHeight)
    
    // The chosen width and height that will be used to scale the image.
    val newWidth : Int = (sourceWidth * percentage).toInt()
    val newHeight : Int = (sourceHeight * percentage).toInt()
    
    // #######################################################################################
    
    // Scale image to chosen dimensions.
    val scaledBitmap : Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceAsBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true)
    
    // Compress the image to the chosen quality and format.
    val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    scaledBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream)
    
    // Create file for the scaled & compressed image.
    val compressedFile : File = createFile(outputStream.toByteArray(), source, fileNameSuffix) ?: return null
    
    copyExifData(source, compressedFile, newWidth, newHeight)
    
    outputStream.close()
    
    return compressedFile
}


private fun createFile(byteArray : ByteArray, source : Uri, nameSuffix : String) : File?
{
    return try
    {
        val sourceAsDocumentFile : DocumentFile? = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, source)
        
        val sourceFileName : String = sourceAsDocumentFile?.name?.substringBefore(".") ?: System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
        
        val finalFileName = "$sourceFileName-$nameSuffix.jpg"
        
        val file : File = StorageUtils.createFile(finalFileName)
        
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        fileOutputStream.write(byteArray)
        fileOutputStream.close()
        
        file
    }
    catch (exception : Exception)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.print("failed to create file", exception)
        null
    }
}


private fun copyExifData(source : Uri, destination : File, width : Int, height : Int)
{
    try
    {
        val sourceFileDescriptor : FileDescriptor = context.contentResolver?.openFileDescriptor(source, "r")?.fileDescriptor ?: return
        
        val sourceFileExif = ExifInterface(sourceFileDescriptor)
        
        val destinationFileExif = ExifInterface(destination)
        
        destinationFileExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, height.toString())
        destinationFileExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, width.toString())
        
        val orientation : String = sourceFileExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION) ?: ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL.toString()
        
        destinationFileExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, orientation)
        
        sourceFileExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME)?.let {
            destinationFileExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, it)
        }
        
        sourceFileExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE)?.let {
            destinationFileExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE, it)
        }
        
        sourceFileExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)?.let {
            destinationFileExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, it)
        }
        
        sourceFileExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE)?.let {
            destinationFileExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, it)
        }
        
        destinationFileExif.saveAttributes()
    }
    catch (exception : Exception)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.print("failed to copy exif data", exception)
    }
}


private fun getBitmapFromUri(uri : Uri) : Bitmap?
{
    return try
    {
        val parcelFileDescriptor : ParcelFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver?.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r") ?: return null
        val fileDescriptor : FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor
        val image : Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
        parcelFileDescriptor.close()
        image
    }
    catch (exception : Exception)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.print("error decoding image using bitmap factory", exception)
        null
    }
}
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem?
i also want to know what is the difference between these three method for getting bitmap from uri? and which one is better?

method 1 :

```
val bitmap = if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.P)
{
    val source : ImageDecoder.Source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, uri)
    ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
}
else
{
    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, uri)
}
```

methode 2 :

```
val parcelFileDescriptor : ParcelFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver?.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r") ?: return null
val fileDescriptor : FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor
val image : Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
parcelFileDescriptor.close()
```

methode 3 :

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.path)
```

Comment: I'm talking about an image size, so it's clear that it's in mb

Comment: ok, i changed it to MB

Comment: `and in the exif data the height and the width are -1` Unclear where things go wrong. Are you calling copyExifData with -1, -1 ? If so then you calculated them for newWidth and newHeight. Please elaborate.

Comment: yes I think there is a problem when copying exif, but I don't think the problem is the initial content, because the other data (gps, datetime...) are also not writed. I made a mistake doing it in a try catch without handling the exception. I will handle this.
but I don't think the exif is the only problem, because the image size doesn't change too, it's always at 5-6MB. can it be because of decoding to bitmap?

Comment: You did not react on the things i said in my last comment. Sorry, i cannot follow you. Just answer/confirm my questions please.

Answer (score 0):

This method is going to be very dependent on the source data, and what format the image originally is in.  What you're doing is reencoding the image into a lossy format, after possibly cropping it.  If it was a PNG originally, you'll have a slightly smaller file- probably.  It may not be, it depends on how well the image compresses.  If it was a JPG, you're going to lose a lot of quality by re-encoding it (because both encodings were lossy) and you may or may not get a smaller file-  if it was already at 80% or lower quality it won't likely get much smaller, but it will be poorer quality.

Some images just don't compress well. Compression requires patterns of data.  If your image doesn't have that, it won't compress.  That's why icons (mostly blank space) compress so much better than photos (mostly dynamic data).  If you absolutely need it to be smaller, you need to drop that quality down even further.  Or rethink your requirements.

As for the exif data being wrong-  you're catching Exception in your code to write it.  Most likely an error was thrown.  Catch it normally (catching Exception is almost always a bad idea anyway) and fix it.  But without knowing what it was we can't really help.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I wanted to tell you that I compress JPG images captured with the photo camera. in 95% of smartphones, the size of the image after compression does not exceed 1mb. on the other hand before compression, the images captured by my phone are around 4mb.

it is true that I lose quality, but not much. at least according to my needs.

I got acceptable quality with a satisfactory reduction in file size.

but okay, I'm going to copy the exif in another way, it was not necessary to catch the error as I had done.